# string detection in dplyr filter results in evaluation error

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using R and  the `dplyr` library to perform string search for a character data.frame that consists of one column. Performing an AND operation on two strings for conditional test to location data. I have an error in `dplyr::filter` evaluation.

```
str(dec2013.data)
'data.frame':   10481 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Routing.SYSID: chr  "L839ITSRLX001TGU3" "L839SMARLX001TGU3" 
"L839CRJRLX001TGU3" "L839BUARLX001TGU3"

dec2013.data.route1 <- data.frame()
dec2013.data.route1 <- dec2013.data %>% 
  filter(str_detect(Routing.SYSID,"L839" & 
  str_detect(Routing.SYSID,"TGU3")))

dput()
"L839CHHFNL626TGU3", "L839HPHFNL626TGU3", "L839NHBFNL626TGU3", 
"L839BMQFNL626TGU3", "L839JUCFNL626TGU3", "L839KJYFNL626TGU3", 
"L839KPPFNL626TGU3", "L839IWHFNL626TGU3", "L839NOFFNL626TGU3", 
"L839DXQFNL626TGU3", "L839TMUFNL626TGU3", "L839RGCFNL626TGU3"
```

> Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) :    Evaluation error: operations are
>   possible only for numeric, logical or complex types.

Comment: Change this bit `filter(str_detect(Routing.SYSID,"L839") & 
  str_detect(Routing.SYSID,"TGU3"))`

Answer (score 2):

you just have wrong parenthesis. This should work:

```
dec2013.data %>% 
    filter(str_detect(Routing.SYSID,"L839"), str_detect(Routing.SYSID,"TGU3"))
```

Comment: thank you. I was still thinking of & for two conditionals, forgot that filter can work as that which you showed.

Comment: glad I could help. Please consider accepting the answer as well.

Comment: thanks Chettt - I am working on my master of data science project now

Comment: in some online resources, I have seen `filter(str_detect(var, "str1"|"str2"))`, but I got the same error as the OP. I wonder if this was due to an update in stingr or dplyr... but breaking it out as in this solution worked for me.